# get the sum of input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello so here is my html

```
<li><label for=secure>Account #</label><input id="ID_1" name="ID_1"  required></li>
<li><label for=secure>Account #</label><input id="ID_2" name="ID_2"  required></li>
<li><label for=secure>Account #</label><input id="ID_3" name="ID_3"  required></li>
```

these are populated dynamically. 
I would like to put get the total amount of all these fields (they are numeric).
I believe I would have to use the `each` function in jquery but I am not sure how to go about using it in this specific situation.so pretty much the sum of each input that has an id that starts with `ID_`

Comment: You could grab the non-dynamic part.. `input[id*="ID_"]` as a jQuery selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var total = 0;

$('[id^="ID_"]').each(function(_, el) {
    total += +(el.value);
});
```

Comment: great adeneo..i was answering with usual code..this is way better! upvote for you!